# knockout computed object not working when working with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout, The problem is that I try to load object from JSON and also use computed value
please see jsfiddle example and tell me what I am doing wrong 
it should display "Hello World" + "start date" (in the third line)
http://jsfiddle.net/qp86wbdt/3/

```
self.starttextt= ko.computed(function() {
    return  " Hello world " + this.start();
}, this);
```

it may worth mentioning that this computed object lives in "events" object (which is loaded from json) while "events" object live in the ViewModel object.

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: You never map to your Event object. Either iterate through JSON data and create event from each item and push it to KO events array, or use mapping plugin.

Comment: Hi MiBu can you provide example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite some problems with your current approach:

You need to fix your `Event` function to take some parameter to fill in with data:

```
 function Event(data) {
     var self = this;
     self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
     self.start = ko.observable(data.start);
     self.starttextt = ko.computed(function () {
         return " Hello world " + this.start();
     }, this);
 }
```

Then writing `var data = [Event];` just create an array with the `Event` function and it does not do any kind of mapping. You need to call `map` on your `objs` array:

```
 var objs = JSON.parse(js);
 var data = objs.map(function (e) {
     return new Event(e)
 });
```

And you need to use `data` in your viewModel instead of `obj`

```
 var viewModel = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.events = ko.observableArray(data);
 };
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6938v22/).

However you don't need to write all these mapping code because there is already a plugin exists called [Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which is built to handle these kind of situations.

Here is your sample rewritten with the mapping plugin:

```
 var mapping = {
     create: function (options) {
         var event = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
         event.starttextt = ko.computed(function () {
             return " Hello world " + event.start();
         }, event);
         return event;
     }
 }
 var viewModel = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.events = ko.mapping.fromJSON(js, mapping);
 };
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5shd784/).

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, the first solution worked for me, appreciate